# How to make an array with custom indexes(MAPPING)?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

UPDATE:

```
struct TotalVotes {
    uint256 value;
}
mapping(uint256 => TotalVotes) public allVotes;
```

This works, BUT WHY DO I NEED TO use a struct? I only want single value which is an integer? Can't i do it without the struct?

Basically i need to store a dynamic amount of uint256 - which are IDs(unique identifiers).

How do I do this so I could then access numbers for each ID?

for example, i want to get uint256 values for ID, like this

myArray[123]
and
myArray[9843594]

TLDR: Need to store multiple uint256, that differ by ID which is an uint256. How do I create a mapping for it?
An array where values are uint256, but you don't identify it by an address but by ID(uint256?)

I tried doing it like this

```
uint256 public numberOfVotes;
mapping(uint256 => numberOfVotes) public totalVotes;
```

but this doesn't work...

Comment: Does this help? [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Comment: I don't understand why can't i map uint256 to an uint256?

But if i create a struct with a single value that is uint256 and map the struct, then it works. So i need the struct for it?

Comment: You may be interested in using the newly introduced [User Defined Value Types](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/09/27/user-defined-value-types/).

Comment: @smenir443 Something like `mapping(uint256 => uint256) public totalVotes` works.

Comment: @Ismael thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for